# Adding The Safety Remove Hardware Option To The Desktop Right-Click Contextual Menu?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, context-menu, safely-remove-hardware

Is it possible to add **The Safety Remove Hardware Option** to the Windows desktop right-click contextual menu to aid in the removal of usb devices ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The people over at SevenForums have provided a nice .reg file that you can run to add some registry values so that it appears in the context menu: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/195984-safely-remove-hardware-add-desktop-context-menu.html

Alternatively, you can do it yourself using regedit.exe and adding these registry values:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DesktopBackground\Shell\Safely Remove Hardware]
"Icon"="hotplug.dll,-100"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DesktopBackground\Shell\Safely Remove Hardware\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\control.exe hotplug.dll"
```

Just remove `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DesktopBackground\Shell\Safely Remove Hardware` if you want to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

In Vista or 7 unlock us has a nice and easy tutorial to do just this. http://unlockforus.blogspot.com/2008/07/vistaxp-add-safely-remove-hardware.html

For Windows OS there are not many areas that you can't add commands

Comment: Welcome to SU!  Link-only answers are considered a no-no due to possible future link-rot.  Please include pertinent information in your answers.